# Problem in creating instances (creating two sample modules)

Tags: 7, entities, database, installation

I just started learning how to develop modules in drupal 7 using entities.
I am creating two modules Artwork and Windfarm

in artwork i am adding 2 custom fields (artist_name and Location)
in Windfarm i am adding 4 custom fields

Following is for windfarm

```
 foreach ($instances as $instance) {
    $instance['entity_type'] = 'node';
    $instance['bundle'] = 'bndlwindfarm';
    field_create_instance($instance);
  }
}
```

this is fro artwork

```
foreach ($instances as $instance) {
    $instance['entity_type'] = 'node';
    $instance['bundle'] = 'artwork';
    field_create_instance($instance);
  }
```

both these code are part of function which implements hook_install()

problem is :

if i install artwork i am able to see 2 fields and after that if install windfarm i am not able to see my 4 custom fields

in reverse way

if i install windfarm first i am able to see 4 fields and if i install artwork after this i am not able to see 2 fields of artworks..

i am not getting why it is happening??
both of them has same entity_type i.e node and different bundle names??

Expected behavior : if i install both modules in each module i should see custom feilds
let me know where i am going wrong